# Getting and Error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, module, error

I'm installing [SEO Suite Installation](http://docs.swissuplabs.com/m2/extensions/seo-suite/installation/composer/) via Composer but during installation I'm getting an error. Can anyone help me for the solution of this. Screenshot of error is attached.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty obvious you have a dependance `psr/cache` that requires php 8 and you are still under php 7

Check for a version of that module (less than 3.0.0 apparently) working with your current php version. Or update to php 8.